# Invoking granular methods in Akka

Tags: scala, akka

Assume I have three methods in an Akka actor that I need to invoke from an actor client:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case req1: Request1 => sender ! method1()
    case req2: Request2 => sender ! method2()
    case req3: Request3 => sender ! method3()
  }
}
```

I need to invoke these methods in different combinations, for example:

method1, method2

method3

method1, method2, method3

I could have in the client the following method to invoke `method1`:

```
def invokeMethod1 () {
      val system = ActorSystem("system")
      implicit val timeout = Timeout(120 seconds)
      val actor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myactor")
      val future = actor ? Request1
      val result = Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
}
```

What is the best strategy to invoke methods in different combinations? should I have a `invokeMethod1`, `invokeMethod2` and `invokeMethod3` (note that each one initializes the actor system)? Or should I combine in the actor itself the methods, for example `method1and2`? Is there any other preferred way?

Answer (score -1):

i recommend use to for-loop ,

```
  def invokeMetod1:Future[Int] = ???
  def invokeMetod2:Future[Int] = ???
  def invokeMetod3:Future[Int] = ???
  val a =
    for{
      _1 <- invokeMetod1
      _3 <- invokeMetod3
      _2 <- invokeMetod2
    }yield
      _1 + _2 + _3
```

it can sequential execution (invokeMetod1 and then invokeMetod3 and then invokeMetod2)